# Delphi DBGrid how to change the value when displayed

Tags: delphi, cell, dbgrid

I need to change the contents of the cell for display only. I do it in DrawColumnCell:

```
if Column.FieldName = 'UUID' then
  begin
     with (Sender as TDBGrid).Canvas do
     begin
         FillRect(Rect);
         strTemp := (Sender as TDBGrid).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('UUID').AsString;
         strTemp := RightStr(strTemp, Length(strTemp) - LastDelimiter('-', strTemp));

         TextOut(Rect.Right - 2 - (Sender as TDBGrid).Canvas.TextWidth(strTemp), Rect.Top + 2, strTemp);

     end;
  end;
```

UUID - has an appearance 'SHRYU-5TRP0-RT-898-763523561294'. Оnly need to be displayed '763523561294'.

The code from above copes with this, but if you select this cell, it turns out that the original value and mine and they overlap each other are substituted. How to avoid this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: One way is to use persistent fields in the TDataSet and the OnGetText() event for this field there. Or hook up the event at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnGetText()` event for the underlying field of the DataSet is a more appropriate place to do this. Use persistent fields or hook up an event at runtime.

```
procedure TForm1.FDMemTable1AGUIDGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
    DisplayText: Boolean);
Var
  strTemp : string;
begin
  if DisplayText then
  begin
     strTemp := Sender.AsString;
     strTemp := RightStr(strTemp, Length(strTemp) - LastDelimiter('-', strTemp));
     Text := strTemp;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I can't understand where to enter it. I have - FDConnection, FDQuery, DataSource, DBGrid. I don't have FDMemTable1.

Comment: FDQuery, right click and select Fields Editor. Or search for things like `Delphi persistent fields` online and read up on them.